# How to refresh the screen in tkinter to show a new label text?

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

Down below is my code, I am working on a fun hangman game for myself to get used to Tkinter library/ GUI creation and the python language. I have hit a bit of a snag on refreshing the GUI after the user inputs a guess to give the user feedback using a label. I read to use a label so you can have a string variable attached to it so you can change the text but I cannot figure it out. As well for whatever reason, my Tkinter label "text_out" is not showing. Thanks for your help in advance! Also, I am new and a beginner programmer so any input on how to better organize myself would be great as well.

```
    from tkinter import *
    import random

    root = Tk()
    root.wm_title("Hangman")

    w = Canvas(root, width=1000,height=650)
    #drawing the hangmaan image setup
    w.create_rectangle(250,0,450,25, fill = "brown") #top beam
    w.create_rectangle(250,0,275,100, fill = "brown") #hanging part
    w.create_rectangle(475,0,450,400, fill = "brown") #middle upright
    w.create_rectangle(300,400,600,425, fill = "brown") #platform
    w.pack()

    alphabet = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y",
        "z"] #keeps track of letters used
    words = ["atmosphere", "miscellaneous","muffins","junk","pajamas","engineering","privilege","amplifier","countryside","python",
     "magic","hats","flash","clock","ceiling"] #random word choices for the answer

    word_choice = random.choice(words) #chooses word from list of words for         the answer
    print(word_choice) #for debugging
    mult = len(word_choice) #length of word to create underscore string 
    underscores = "_ "*mult #underscore string 
    print(underscores) #for debugging
    w.create_text(500,600, font= ("Purisa", 48), text = underscores) #underscores in gui output

    guess_out = "$" #text varavable to be changed as a result of user guess
    text_out = Label(root,font=("Purisa", 18),textvariable="Test").place(x=650,y=200) #results of user guess text on screen

    guess_bar_label = Label(root, font = ("Purisa", 20), text = "Guess: ").place(x=600, y=285) #label for the text bar
    guess_var = StringVar() #varaiable for the text bar
    guess_bar = Entry(root, textvariable=guess_var).place(x=700, y=300) #text bar for user input


    def Guess():
        #logic test 
        print(guess_var.get())
        if len(str(guess_var.get()))==1: #makes sure input is only one charactar
            print("one char")
            if str(guess_var.get()) in alphabet: #makes sure is still a choice and not one they have picked already
                print("in alphabet") #for debugging
                guess_out = "that is in the alphabet" #GUI output text change for user to see
                root.update_idletasks() #failed attemped to refresh screen
                alphabet.remove(str(guess_var.get())) #removes choice after use and guess goes through

        elif len(str(guess_var.get()))>1: #result if input is too long
            print("too many chaactar")


    w = Button (root,command=Guess, text="Check").place(x=850, y=300) #submit button for users guess from entry bar


    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a tkinter `StringVar`, and use it to set the value of `textvariable` in your label.
The following shows you how the label updates works with the letter from the entry box, which answers your question. (It does not fix the other problems in your code).

```
import tkinter as tk
import random


def guess():
    global guess_out
    guessed = guess_bar.get()
    print(guessed)
    if len(guessed) == 1:
        print("one char")
        if str(guessed) in alphabet:
            guess_out.set(guessed)
            alphabet.remove(guessed)

    elif len(str(guess_var.get())) > 1:
        print("too many characters")


if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.wm_title("Hangman")

    w = tk.Canvas(root, width=1000, height=650)

    w.create_rectangle(250, 0, 450, 25, fill="brown")
    w.create_rectangle(250, 0, 275, 100, fill="brown")
    w.create_rectangle(475, 0, 450, 400, fill="brown")
    w.create_rectangle(300, 400, 600, 425, fill="brown")
    w.pack()

    alphabet = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
    words = ["atmosphere", "miscellaneous", "muffins", "junk", "pajamas", "engineering", "privilege", 
             "amplifier", "countryside", "python", "magic", "hats", "flash", "clock", "ceiling"]

    word_choice = random.choice(words)
    mult = len(word_choice)
    underscores = "_ " * mult
    w.create_text(500, 600, font=("Purisa", 48), text=underscores)

    guess_out = tk.StringVar()
    guess_out.set("$")

    text_out = tk.Label(root, font=("Purisa", 18), textvariable=guess_out)
    text_out.place(x=650, y=200)

    guess_bar_label = tk.Label(root, font=("Purisa", 20), text="Guess: ")
    guess_bar_label.place(x=600, y=285)

    guess_bar = tk.Entry(root)
    guess_bar.place(x=700, y=300)

    w = tk.Button(root, command=guess, text="Check")
    w.place(x=850, y=300)

    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a button that deletes the frame you have your current display in. When that is deleted draw a new frame in the parent and adding all of your new code with the refreshed frame